# What 17 decimal places of precision means in number js mdn doc?

Tags: javascript

```js
const a = 10;
const b = 0.123456789123456789;

console.log((a + b).toFixed(17));


// 10.12345678912345726
```

As you can see from example above, `.12345678912345` , only this part are shown correctly , as I understand Javascript only consider 15 places precision ( including `.`). If I will change 10 to 100 , it will be same amount , but I was thinking it should be 17 places precision by MDN doc. What doesn't this phrase exactly mean `17 decimal places of precision` ?

If I will show it without `.toFixed()` method , it will show same 15 precision `10.123456789123457`  - response of `a + b`

Url: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number

Comment: What do you mean by "correctly"? It's not clear to me what you're asking.

Comment: All this depends above all on the way in which the numerical values are implemented in the systems. Javascript is not intended to be used to make precision calculations, the integer values are limited to that of a processor register, and the floating values are represented in precision and approximation in an exponential representation

Comment: 726 - goes after number 5 in response , but it should be 6789 -  as I understand js have some limitation for numbers which can be shown after . , but how much numbers is it consider  ? I was thinking 17 ( by doc ) , but seems I get it wrong @deceze

Comment: You're aware of https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/476…? Do you need to dig into any more detail?

Comment: These are some good explanation for this problem  https://0.30000000000000004.com/  and  https://docs.python.org/release/2.5.1/tut/node16.html

Answer (score 2):

According to `JS/ECMAScript` specification, the `Number type` uses double-precision floating point which has `64-bit` format (`binary64`), consists of a sign bit (determines positive or negative value), `11` exponent bits and `52` fraction bits (each digit represents `4`-bits, hence `64`-bit has `16` digits):

> The Number type representing the double-precision 64-bit format IEEE
> 754-2008 values as specified in the IEEE Standard for Binary
> Floating-Point Arithmetic.

The maximum positive number which can be represented properly using double precision is `9007199254740992`, which can be achieved by using `Math.pow(2, 53)`. If the number range is between `Math.pow(2, 53)` and `Math.pow(2, 54)` (or between `Math.pow(2, -53)` and `Math.pow(2, -54)`), only even numbers can be represented properly because the exponent bits will affect `LSB` (least-significant bit) on the fraction bits.

Let's review the large number part:

```
var x = 12345678912345.6789

var x = new Number(12345678912345.6789)
```

This number contains more than `52` fractional bits (`72` bits in total), hence the rounding used to keep the fractional bits to `52`.

Also with this decimal number:

```
var x = new Number(.12345678912367890)
```

This number contains `68` fractional bits, hence the last zero is chopped off to keep `64`-bit length.

Usually numeric representation larger than `9007199254740992` or smaller than `1.1102230246251565E-16` are stored as literal strings instead of `Number`. If you need to compute very large numbers, there are certain external libraries available to perform arbitrary precision arithmetic.

If you want to cast more then 16 points after the decimal point you can either:

- Use literal string to represent your number
- Use external libraries like [math.js](https://mathjs.org/docs/datatypes/bignumbers.html), [BigInteger.js](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) or [strint](https://github.com/rauschma/strint) library.

Comment: By your description 52 bits for fraction ( fraction as I understand is digits which comes after   .) 13 * 4 = 52 , which mean what it should only hold 13 digits after point, but as as described above , it seems like 14 digits , and also from what you have described as I understand 1 bit goes to store info about is it possitive or negative ? @n-ata